# Convert lines of code into script for archlinux on usb (dos2unix and $HOME not working)

Tags: unix, archlinux

I need to run some commands as fast as possible after boot a asrchlinux from usb. I tried to make a script file (created in windows using notepad and then renaming it with .sh) with the following commands, but obviously it hasn't worked.

The commands I need to run are:

```
cd /
umount /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/
mount -t efivarfs rw /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/
cd /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/
chattr -i "gpu-power-prefs-fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9" 
rm gpu-power-prefs-fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9
printf "\x07\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00"> /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/gpu-power-prefs-fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9
chattr +i "/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/gpu-power-prefs-fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9"
cd /
umount /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/
"reboot"
```

I tried to change cd / into cd $HOME and tried also to do the "dos2unix" thing, but after some maybe simple errors I cannot understand I gave up.

It would be great if I could test the script in windows, if possible, maybe with a particular software, just to be sure it's working without errors.

I need to run this code on a mac machine that is unable to boot.

Answer (score 0):

1: you can not assume that $HOME is set while the system is booting at this stage. Let it alone and use absolute file/dir names.

2: writing unix scripts with windows notepad is not very good. You could try notepad++ or other better editors to save the file with the correct end of line (LF only, not CR+LF).

3: dos2unix is ok, but also use the file(1) command to check what file you have.

4: the first line of your script should be:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

to ensure it can be executed.

5: testing a unix script in windows is hard, and even harder if you fiddle with OS internals like your script seems to do.